# Opening an android app with html code

Tags: javascript, android, css, html

Is it possible to use html5, css and javascript to open an android application?
I searched online but none of the answers I found so far where usefull for me.

Im trying to create an android app made in html and css and act like an android launcher. The layout is done but I cant find out how I can actualy launch apps with it. 
edit: I used phonegap to create the apk and installed it on my phone.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create android applications with html, js, css you should use:

1. http://phonegap.com/
2. http://cordova.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a Java-JavaScript bridge. Take a look at this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html